# If I put a smoker in a shed, does my exhaust have to be at the top of my shed? (Does exhaust height matter)?

Tags: safety-standards, camp-fire-cooking

I'm looking to purchase a " Weber Smokey Mountain," but wanted to get an enclosure for it so that during cold/rainy/windy weather I can smoke without issues, since I heard it isn't greatly insulated from the elements (which could have to do with it's price-point).

I realized that I could use my shed as a storage/smoking area for my smoker.  I notice there is a 4" or so hole with a vent at the top of my shed (I believe I Saw one on both front and back), but the vents seem to be very narrow (to stop larger-bugs/animals from coming in).  I could replace them, but I also noticed 2 rectangular (2 square panels on top of each other for each window) windows on the side of my shed that seem to open with a screen on the bottom panel for airflow.  I would place my smoker next to one of the 2 windows with the exhaust facing out towards the window.

I am curious if

1. The windows itself would provide enough of a ventilation source for the WSM if I keep the door open there should be a nice draft going from the door to the window which should pull the smoke better; however a door being open will cause temp shifts (the shed still gets cold anyways), wind, and possibly animals to get inside.
2. If it would be better to get a venting fan with louvers and put it in the window's space so the smoke should get pulled out by the powerful vent fan and I shouldn't have any issues.  BUt the thing is, will all of the smoke get pulled, or will it float to the top of my shed and stay there? (I assume the smoke would escape from the vents on top, but I'm not sure if it will be good enough even for just a little trailing smoke).  EDIT:  I also would like to have an intake fan on the other window so that I will get fresh air inside the shed as well, or maybe just keep the other window open(without a fan) to create a nice draft.

:EDIT-END

3. If I should get fans and place them up top where the vents are (but I would have to cut a hole which is what I want to avoid and why I really am happy I found windows in my shed).

My major concern is to make sure that I am not generating too much smoke and creating carbon monoxide.  I will be setting up a few carbon monoxide readers around the smoker, door, etc, and I'm hoping there is a unit that I can get that connects to a mobile device or desktop so I can monitor the shed.  I really do not think I will have an issue with #2, but I want to be safe, but curious what others think.  I'm not sure if creating a cross breeze with #1 will be safe, especially doing longer smokes that will go into the night time where animals roam. That is why I especially like having the shed, and it being fully closed (besides the windows being open, or the fan being on with louvers open, or closed when off).  Which is why #2 seems like my best bet.

Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

EDIT:  I want to keep the smoker enclosed in the shed as much as possible. I want to be able to open the door to the shed, and be able get inside and close it, to tend to the smoker.  This means I need to have most of the smoke leaving, and some fresh air coming inside that I can tend to the smoker without worry.

NOTE: the shed was cold when I went inside it the other day, but that can be fixed in many ways.  The fire from the smoker should warm it up nicely, but I can add other heaters as well, or maybe some insulation.

NOTE:  The shed is wood, so I'm not really sure if the smoker inside a wood shed is even a "smart idea" but I don't see the flames leaving the smoker.

NOTE:  I figured this would be better for "The Great Outdoors" over "Cooking," but if I that is not the case, please feel free to flag the post in order to migrate it.

Comment: Since this seems to be about the shed and not the cooking per se, this might actually be better at https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=smoker

Comment: I'm not really sure where would be best.  I figured people here would know about smokers and smoke fumes being not good, compared to DIY, and cooking would probably have a good idea as well, but DIY would probably be good for ventilation questions, as they probably get rid of solder smoke and such, but that might be different and might not rise like wood smoke does.  Thoughts?  Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about setting something up inside a shed that doesn't have any application in the outdoors (except for producing delicious meat on hikes, but that would be a stretch :) ).

Comment: @imsodin also voting to close, but pointing out you can only enjoy if you survive the likely CO2 poisoning.

Comment: The question is essentially, "Is there some way to make an outdoor use designed charcoal burning appliance safe and not accumulate smoke odors in a loosely specified indoor situation."  That is far too vague.

Comment: @JamesJenkins which is the whole point I'm asking if/how I can ventilate it.  IT's also not about CO2 it's about CO poisoning, and trying to prevent it.

Answer (score 5):

Safety guidelines for this smoker specifically state that it's not suitable for indoor use.

It's quite literally the first thing on the instructions

https://www.riversidegardencentre.co.uk/pdf/2009_Smokey_Mountain_Cooker.pdf

> DANGER
>   Failure to follow the Dangers, Warnings, and Cautions contained in this Owner’s Manual may result in serious bodily injury, death, 
>   or fire causing damage to property.
>
> Do not use indoors! This smoker is designed for outdoor use only. If used indoors, toxic fumes will accumulate and cause serious bodily injury or death.

By the looks of the design it isn't possible to seal it to a chimney so there's no way to control the exhaust gases/CO. What you'd probably find if you ran it in the shed was that the CO alarms would give you no peace.

If you want to run it under a shelter then a small shelter with no more than 3 walls and a roof is possibly acceptable to ensure adequate ventilation for you to share a space with it. Basically no more than wind and rain screens.

Comment: That warning is usually there to tell people not to run the smokers inside their own homes, so that CO/CO2 wont get sucked into their heating/cooling system and pump the gases throughout your home.  My shed is not connected to my home at all.  Why would an exhaust fan not work in this situation?  It should be able to suck air from the smoker very well.

Comment: @XaolingBao, that warning is there to tell you not to be in a confined space with a source of Carbon Monoxide. It's the same reason you don't use a camp stove or bbq in a tent, it'll kill you.

Comment: Yes, of course, it also mentions to not use this smoker inside a tent.  Tents are small usually, and don't have any vents.  I understand that using it inside your garage, or anywhere connected to your home is a bad idea, but I'm asking about venting it from a shed, which I have read on other sites is okay, as others do it, but not 100% about that. My issue is where does my ventilation need to be, at the top, or will venting the smoke from a window above the smoker's exhaust be enough, in addition to the vents that already exist at the top of the shed.  But maybe I shouldn't do this in the shed

Comment: @XaolingBao, are you willing to bet your life that it's ok to do it in the shed? Because that's what you're doing, regardless of what other sites say.

Comment: CO poisoning is cumulative. Wikipedia states "Unconsciousness after 2–3 breaths. Death in less than three minutes." for high levels. Upto you if you think it can get that high in your shed or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will create CO.  The question is if the CO level is dangerous when you open the door to tend to the cooker.  Put it by the door and don't enter the shed while cooking.

Comment: I understand it will create the gasses, but my concern is how I should be venting them out.  I do want to let some air get inside when i open the door, but if there is bad weather outside I do not want to keep it open for long, and will want to close it to tend to the meat.  I might be in there while it's smoking for a few mins, and cant risk doing something stupid, which is why I want to make sure I'm venting properly.

Comment: Why do you need to close the door to tend the meat?   I own one of those cookers and spend very little time tending.  For that matter leaving it outside would not be much difference in charcoal.

Comment: OH, happy day.  The down votes continue.

Comment: NOTE:  I didn't downvote you. I figured the temps during the cold, or other bad weather could affect the smoker, even though it wouldn't be near the door.  I don't HAVE to close it, but figured it would be best, or at least have it open a bit.  I don't exactly have to keep it open if I get air from the other open window.

Comment: Actually smoker works better in cooler weather as better air flow.  Put in proper fuel to get the desired temp.

Comment: unrelated, but since you said you have a WSM, how do YOU feel it fares in cold/rainy/etc weather?  Do you feel that it needs an enclosure, or what are your thoughts?  I've read a lot of reviews where people had to get some sort of cooking cover, or place some sort of weather barrier around the unit.

Comment: For sure I would not put it in my shed.  This is getting a little broad and right now I am -1 so I will probably just delete.

Comment: I too have noticed a disturbing trend. Might be time to ask the Mods to have a look at whats going on.

Comment: @mattnz I am cool and don't think mods are the fix here.

Comment: This doesn't attempt to answer the question...  While it's not wrong, the OP asked for ways to properly vent the shed (if it's possible) so it's safe to be inside...  People have been doing just that for centuries

Comment: @Taegost OP does not express vent so safe be inside.  Really people have been making smoke sheds you can be inside for centuries?  You do know that CO poisoning is cumulative?

Comment: @Paparazzi The OP explicitly states "I want to be able to open the door to the shed, and be able get inside and close it, to tend to the smoker. This means I need to have most of the smoke leaving, and some fresh air coming inside that I can tend to the smoker without worry."

Comment: @Taegost That was an edit AFTER I posted my answer.  Let it go.

Answer (score -2):

In a dirty kitchen, Cooking shed. A chimney or stack. Needs be 6 inch's above roof peak. For proper draft. So no back draft. Were the pipe goes threw the roof you need double wall vent pipe. Cut a 12 inch square hole in the roof. Next lay over the hole a 24 inch sheet metal. Cut a hole round in the center with tin snips. like triangles. This is fitted down the double wall pipe. Onto the roof wood. Keeps rain out. Keeps heat from wood so no fire there. Next a dirty kitchen needs vented. So you will need leave a window open. Or door when cooking. On a wood roof this is important to prevent fires & proper venting. Nothing better than a plain stove pipe to set a roof on fire in a cook shed. Be sure & check vent pipes often. They can have no holes in then were a spark or hot cinder can escape. Keep cooker away from walls. Use cheap sheet metal on the walls near them to deflect heat & sparks.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, this seems to have good info.

Comment: @XaolingBao This user has a history of barely legible posts with a content ranging from pure and obvious trolling to seemingly (I don't know much about some topics) useful (this post falls in this category -> no vote from me). I still make myself try to understand and only down-/delete-vote if I am sure it is BS, but I guess there are those that don't do that anymore before hitting "Delete" in the queue.

Comment: It's a reasonable, if a little scrambled, description of how to put a chimney through a wooden roof. It's just not really suitable for this situation because the burner in question won't take a chimney.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just not sure if I would need a smoke stack coming out of my shed.  It seems that a chimney is designed that way for fireplaces.  Not sure if it what I would need in my situation.